# Retrieve KEYWORDS from META tag in a HTML WebPage using JAVA

Tags: java, html, collections, meta-tags

I want to retrieve all the content words from a HTML WebPage and all the keywords contained in the META TAG of the same HTML webpage using Java.
For example, consider this html source code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "keywords" content = "deception, intricacy, treachery">
</head>
<body>
My very short html document. 
<br>
It has just 2 'lines'.
</body>
</html>
```

The CONTENT WORDS here are: *my*, *very*, *short*, *html*, *document*, *it*, *has*, *just*, *lines*

**Note:** The punctuation and the number '2' are ruled out.

The KEYWORDS here are: *deception*, *intricacy*, *treachery*

I have created a class for this purpose called WebDoc, this is as far as I have been able to get.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class WebDoc {

    protected URL _url;
    protected Set<String> _contentWords;
    protected Set<String> _keyWords

    public WebDoc(URL paramURL) {
        _url = paramURL;
    }

    public Set<String> getContents() throws IOException {
        //URL url = new URL(url);
        Set<String> contentWords = new TreeSet<String>();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // Process each line.
            contentWords.add(RemoveTag(inputLine));
            //System.out.println(RemoveTag(inputLine));
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(contentWords);
        _contentWords = contentWords;
        return contentWords;
    }    

    public String RemoveTag(String html) {
        html = html.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
        html = html.replaceAll("&","");
        return html;
    }



    public Set<String> getKeywords() {
        //NO IDEA !
        return null;
    }

    public URL getURL() {
        return _url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after the answer from RedSoxFan about the meta-keywords, you only need to split your content lines.
You can use a similar method there:

Instead of

```
contentWords.add(RemoveTag(inputLine));
```

use

```
contentWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(RemoveTag(inputLine).split("[^\\p{L}]+")));
```

- `.split(...)` splits your line at all non-letters (I hope this works, please try and report), giving back an array of substrings, which each should contain only of letters, and some empty strings between.
- `Arrays.asList(...)` wraps this array in a list.
- `addAll(...)` adds all the elements of this array to the set, but not duplicates).

At the end you should delete the empty string `""` from your contentWords-Set.

Answer (score 1):

Process each line and use

```
public Set<String> getKeywords(String str) {
        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
        str = str.trim();
        if (str.toLowerCase().startsWith("<meta ")) {
           if (str.toLowerCase().matches("<meta name\\s?=\\s?\"keywords\"\\scontent\\s?=\\s?\".*\"/?>")) {
               // Returns only whats in the content attribute (case-insensitive)
               str = str.replaceAll("(?i)<meta name\\s?=\\s?\"keywords\"\\scontent\\s?=\\s?\"(.*)\"/?>","$1");
               for (String st:str.split(",")) s.add(st.trim());
               return s;
           }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If you need an explanation, let me know.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the content lines. Paŭlo Ebermann gave a good answer, I would just check to see if it is in the body tag otherwise you will get information from the head also